# Seleccionar una lista de dos elementos relacionados en comun en sql con entityFramework y linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Tengo una lista de persona que esta relacionadas con en una tabla comités y en otra tabla tipos persona, necesito devolver la lista de personas de un comité y también devolver la lista de personas de un tipo
nota:devolver las personas que devuelvo de la relación con el comité no tienen que estar filtrada por tipo, solo devolver la lista sin filtro

tengo algo como esto:

```
   var lp = bd.Instituciones
            .Where(x => x.IdInstitucion == idInstitucion)
            .Select(x => x.Comites.Select(c => c.ComitesPersonas.Select(p => p.Persona)).ToList() && x.Personas.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría en varios pasos, si la LINQ la vas a usar con expresiones lambda:

```
var comitesInstitucion = Instituciones
    .Where(ins => ins.IdInstitucion == idInstitucion)
    .SelectMany(ins => ins.Comites);

var personasComite = ComiteInstitucion
    .SelectMany(com => com.ComitesPersonas)
    .Select(comPer => comPer.persona); 

var personasComiteTipo = personasComite
    .Where(per => per.tipo == tipoPersona);
```

Se asignarían los siguientes tipos para cada una de las LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Comite> comitesInstitución;
IEnumerable<Persona> personasComite;
IEnumerable<Persona> personasComiteTipo;
```

En *personasComite* tendrias una lista de personas de todos los comites de una institución, aunque puedes agregar un *Where* si te interesa un comité en concreto justo antes del *SelectMany*.

En *personasComiteTipo* tendrías una lista de personas de un tipo dado de todos los comites de una institución. Me he tenido que inventar un poco la arquitectura, espero que se entienda.

Recuerda que puedes retrasar la evaluación de los enumerables si no las conviertes en lista inmediatamente.

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue hacer dos consultas de las diferentes listas que necesitaba, luego unirlas y la final terminar agrupándolas para que no se repitan valores

```
 //Lista de personas por tipo diferentes de estudiantes
        List<Persona> personasTipo = bdTiposPersona.GetFilter
            (x => x.IdTipoPersona != 7)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Personas.Where(y => y.IdInstitucion == idInstitucion)).ToList();
        //Todas las personas del comite
        List<Persona> personasComites = bdComitesPersona.GetFilter(x => x.Comites.IdInstitucion == idInstitucion).Select(x => x.Persona).ToList();

        //Unir las dos listas
        List<Persona> listaComunidad = personasTipo.Union(personasComites).GroupBy(x => new {
            x.IdPersona,
            x.IdInstitucion,
            x.Nombres,
            x.Apellidos,
            x.NombreCompleto,
            x.RolUsuario,
            x.NombreUser,
            x.Documento,
            x.UrlFoto,
            x.IdArchivoFoto
        }).Select(p=>new Persona
        {
            IdPersona = p.Key.IdPersona,
            IdInstitucion = p.Key.IdInstitucion,
            Nombres = p.Key.Nombres,
            Apellidos = p.Key.Apellidos,
            RolUsuario = p.Key.RolUsuario,
            NombreUser = p.Key.NombreUser,
            Documento = p.Key.Documento,
            UrlFoto = p.Key.UrlFoto,
            IdArchivoFoto= p.Key.IdArchivoFoto
        }).ToList();
```